# Generic T as Spark Dataset[T] constructor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

In the following snippet, the `tryParquet` function tries to load a Dataset from a Parquet file if it exists. If not, it computes, persists and returns back the Dataset plan which was provided:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

sealed trait CustomRow

case class MyRow(
  id: Int,
  name: String
) extends CustomRow

val ds: Dataset[MyRow] =
  Seq((1, "foo"),
      (2, "bar"),
      (3, "baz")).toDF("id", "name").as[MyRow]

def tryParquet[T <: CustomRow](session: SparkSession, path: String, target: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] =
    Try(session.read.parquet(path)) match {
      case Success(df) => df.as[T] // <---- compile error here
      case Failure(_)  => {
        target.write.parquet(path)
        target
      }
    }

val readyDS: Dataset[MyRow] =
    tryParquet(spark, "/path/to/file.parq", ds)
```

However this produces a compile error on `df.as[T]`:

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._
>
> Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
>
> case Success(df) => df.as[T]

One can circumvent this problem by making `tryParquet` cast `df` to return an untyped `DataFrame` and let caller cast to the desired constructor. However is there any solution in the case we want the type to be managed internally by the function?

Answer (score 12):

Looks like it's possible by using an `Encoder` in the type parameter:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

def tryParquet[T <: CustomRow: Encoder](...)
```

This way the compiler can prove that `df.as[T]` is providing an Encoder when constructing the objects.